# LNK2005 " " already defined in main.obj

Tags: c

i don't know why do i get this error

```
//sarver.h
typedef char uint8_t;

typedef enum EN_accountState_t
{
    RUNNING,
    BLOCKED
}EN_accountState_t;

typedef struct ST_accountsDB_t
{
    float balance;
    EN_accountState_t state;
    uint8_t primaryAccountNumber[20];
}ST_accountsDB_t;
```

//------------------------------------------

```
//server.c
#include "server.h"

ST_accountsDB_t validAccounts[250] = { { 2000,RUNNING,"5807007076043875" }
,{ 3000,RUNNING,"5807007076043876" },{ 40000,BLOCKED,"5807007076043877" }
,{ 5000,RUNNING,"5807007076043878" } ,{ 6000,RUNNING,"5807007076043879" } };
```

//------------------------------------------

```
//main.c


#include <stdio.h>

#include "server.c"

int main() {

printf("balance =  %f", validAccounts[0].balance);

}
```

errors>

```
Error   LNK2005 validAccounts already defined in main.obj   
Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

when i place all this code in one file it runs fine but i don't know why it doesn't when it's like this.
if anyone knows what the proplem pleas help

Comment: Don't `#include` source files.  Only header files.

Comment: yeah i did and  it worked

Comment: Typically you want to avoid global variables, but if you must, you define your variable in the source file, and in the accompanying header file you declare it as `extern`.

Comment: ok thank you i'll do that

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line as it defined new instance of this object.

```
#include "server.c"
```

Basically never include `.c` files only header files. Do not put any data or code in the header files, only function prototypes, extern object definitions and data types declaration.

Modify `sarver.h`:

```
#ifndef SARVER_H    //guard
#define SARVER_H

#include <stdint.h>
//typedef char uint8_t;   - it is standard type, do not declare it yourself
typedef enum EN_accountState_t
{
    RUNNING,
    BLOCKED
}EN_accountState_t;

typedef struct ST_accountsDB_t
{
    float balance;
    EN_accountState_t state;
    uint8_t primaryAccountNumber[20];
}ST_accountsDB_t;

extern ST_accountsDB_t validAccounts[250];

#endif
```

And include it into `main.c` file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "sarver.h"

int main() {

printf("balance =  %f", validAccounts[0].balance);

}
```

(`sarver.h' - because this name was given by the question author)

Header files content should be protected by the guards.